# Restricting viewing and editing access to a single worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel document that is accessed by many people.

The data is not private but people get confused because different people need to view different sheets in the workbook.

I want that every sheet has a different password, so when you type in that password, it redirects you to a specific worksheet.

I would give out the different passwords to the corresponding persons or something like that.

I can't save these sheets as single documents because they use each other for calculations.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Pwevaluation
End Sub


Public Function Pwevaluation()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim pw As String

pw = InputBox("Please enter your name", "Access Required", "")
Select Case pw
    Case Is = "hoesl"
        For Each sh In Worksheets
            If sh.Name = "Hinweis" Then
                sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Else
            If sh.Name = "Blatt 1" Then
                sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Else
                sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            End If

            End If
        Next sh
    Case Is = ""
    Case Else
        For Each sh In Worksheets
            If sh.Name = "Deckblatt" Then
                sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Else
                sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            End If
        Next sh
        pw = InputBox("Wrong name, please try again", "Access Required", "")
        Pwevaluation
End Select
End Function
```

When the sheets I'm trying to call are already hidden, I get

> runtime error "1004"

If they are not hidden, everything works.

Comment: look at having all sheets hidden, then on workbook opening event, using an `inputbox` as the simplest, then based on what's entered use an `IF` decision to unhide the sheet.  Have a go, then ask for help here :o)

Comment: A better way might be to create a list with access restrictions for every user, and then have a workbook-open event with `Environ("username")` as argument, and have it hide and show sheets based on the login name of the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I felt like experimenting, this should help you well underway:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Visible = xlSheetVisible
Select Case Environ("Username")
    Case Is = "Plutian"
        For Each sh In Worksheets
            If sh.Name = "Naughty Stuff" Then
                sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Else
                sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            End If
        Next sh
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Insufficient access, see Hoesl for more info"
End Select
End Sub
```

Please note the line `Sheets(Sheets.Count).Visible = xlSheetVisible` is important in this case. If the sheet being unhidden is after the currently visible sheet, it might occur that this sub attempts to hide the last visible sheet (to unhide another sheet later on). This isn't possible and throws an error, therefore this line will unhide the last sheet in any case, so it'll always be active and be hidden last after all other actions are done. This prevents all sheets being hidden at one time.

**EDIT** I suggested another method below, by adding a list of users and access restrictions in a hidden sheet. Since I was interested to get that working, I explored that method as well:

```
Private Sub workbk_Open()
Dim user As Integer, sh As Worksheet

Sheets(Sheets.Count).Visible = xlSheetVisible 'unhide last sheet to prevent all sheets being hidden at once

user = Application.IfError(Application.Match(Environ("username"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:A5"), 0), "0") 'check if user is present in access list

If user > 0 Then
    For Each sh In Worksheets 'loop through sheets
        If Application.IfError(Application.Match(sh.Name, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range(Cells(user + 1, 2), Cells(user + 1, 4)), 0), "0") > 0 Then 'check if sheet is in access list for user
            sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible 'if true, set sheet to visible
            Else
            sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden 'if false, hide sheet
        End If
    Next sh
    Else
    Workbook.Protect 'If user not found, protect workbook to prevent altering
    MsgBox "user not found, see admin for access" 'display error message
End If
End Sub
```

The access list would look like so, where the values represent sheet names. In my code this would be located in sheet3, and only runs from row 2 to 5 for users and column B to D for sheets, but this can be expanded nearly infinitely.

```
A             B             C
Username:     Access:
Plutian       Data sheet    Maintenance sheet
Hoesl         Sheet2        Maintenance sheet
Randomguy     Randomsheet   Sheet3
etc...
```

I hope the comments explain sufficiently, if not, let me know.

**EDIT EDIT**
To update either of these answers with a prompt box with either a password (or by just having the users input their name or a unique key) you can use an input box like so:

```
Dim pw as string
pw = InputBox("Please enter your name", "Access Required", "")
```

And have the code search for the password/input box input in either case:

```
Select Case pw
```

or

```
user = Application.IfError(Application.Match(pw, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:A5"), 0), "0")
```

Just make sure you keep the sheet where you store your passwords hidden at all time when going the second route. And think about how you want to handle wrong passwords.

Comment: So after testing and trying I understood the code (again, im completly new to VBA, only have experience with java and powershell), but the problem is that there are probably around 30 or 40 different users, so is there a beautiful solution for adding every user or do i really have to hardcode every single one?

Comment: There is a way of creating a table with users and restrictions and looping through that, but it would be a completely different approach, and possibly much slower. For now if there is several users with the same restrictions, condense them like so: `Case is = "Plutian", "Hoesl", "Randomguy"` etc.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, i'll see if that's enough for my case

Comment: @Hoesl since I was interested in getting the other method working, I've updated my answer with a working version of that as well.

Comment: Really appreciate your help, thanks a lot for your fast and comprehensive answer

Comment: No problem. I was interested in how it would work so I enjoyed the challenge.

Comment: So apparently the case I'm trying to use this for, every User in the same network has the same profile (there are only user and admin, no personalized user accounts). I didn't do that and i don't have the access to change it. So my idea was to set some Strings as "passwords" for every sheet and depending on what password is entered in the textbox, different sheets get visible. Is that possible to do in VBA?

Comment: @Hoesl, it certainly is possible. It'll be a small modification to the designs above, and I'll update my answer in a bit when I've got it working and tested. In the meantime, can you try putting `debug.print Environ$("username")` and `debug.print application.Username` in the project and see what the window comes back with? If both are just "User" or "Admin" you'll indeed need to go another route. If not this answer can still be used.

Comment: So I'm actually pretty far with the code, the last thing i need to know now is how I can move different sheets in the foreground. Any idea? - Edit: After a quick google search, I'm fine~

Comment: so after doing everything else that was needed, the "1004" Error persists.
As far as i can tell, it comes when I'm trying to close every worksheet before opening another one, because you cant hide every sheet. After changing the order of vbaobjects hoping that would fix it, it still throws me the error. I dont know what to do

Comment: There is a part in above code `Sheets(Sheets.Count).Visible = xlSheetVisible` which will unhide the last sheet. If called before hiding any other sheet, it will unhide the last sheet, and will remain unhidden until the code re-hides it. This prevents the 1004 error of hiding all sheets at once. If that is in and you still get the error, update your question with your current code and I'll take a look.