# Code for the protection of worksheets - unable to be viewed without password for the specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently trying to construct a Workbook consisting of several Worksheets. However, the worksheets should be protected in a way so that they can't be opened unless the correct password is given. Ideally each worksheet should have its own password, i.e. if I were to click on say 'Sheet 2' I would have to enter a password in order to actually see the content of that sheet. I'm quite new to VBA and don't even know if this is even possible.

I have tried to solve the problem without VBA, but Excel does not have that kind of feature and only allows for the protection of cells, etc.

Comment: This is certainly possible. But rather than reinvent the wheel, I suggest you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58286701/11936678) I gave to someone with a similar problem.

Comment: Note that if you try to do this, any coding experienced user is able to easily trick out any VBA solution. There is **no secure way** to protect single worksheets from viewing! • So if you do this be aware that this will only prevent unexperienced users to view your sheet. Don't use this for real secret data!

Comment: Perfect, thx a lot!